# Connection refused when fsockopen()

Tags: php, symfony

After a fresh install of a Symfony [Wallabag](https://github.com/wallabag/wallabag), and running the server I have this response :

> php.DEBUG: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000
> (Connection refused)
> {"type":2,"file":"/my/path/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ServerCommand.php","line":61,"level":28928}

The server have its ports open on `8000`, like the `netstat -tan` command shows us :

> ...
>
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>
> ...

Should I use also a wildcard adress for the port `8000` rule ? If so how do I do this ? I use `firewalld`.